# Why is there no lubridate:::update function?

Tags: r, lubridate

As said in the title: Why is there no such function? Or in a different way: What is the type of the function? When I type `?update` I get something from `stats` package, but there is a lubridate function as described [here](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK2Y6BlafOAhUMCcAKHcItD2gQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv040i03%2Fv40i03.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGzVNr54KvG9RdGUI5pDQPDeUbJKg) on page 7. There also seems to be a `lubridate:::update.Date` function, but I can't find any explanations for that function.

**Backround**: I use the function in a package and I only got it to work after I used the `Depends:` in the decription file. Initially I wanted to use `lubridate::update()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lubridate` package provides the methods `lubridate:::update.Date()` and `lubridate:::update.POSIXt()`. Those functions are not exported into the namespace, but I assume that, by means of function overloading, they are invoked when `update()` is applied to a `POSIX`or `Date` object when the lubridate library is loaded.

The help page `?lubridate:::update.POSIXt` provides some information concerning the `update` function within the `lubridate` package:

> **Description**
>
> update.Date and update.POSIXt return a date with the specified
>   elements updated. Elements not specified will be left unaltered.
>   update.Date and update.POSIXt do not add the specified values to the
>   existing date, they substitute them for the appropriate parts of the
>   existing date.
>
> **Usage**
>
> ## S3 method for class 'POSIXt'
>
> update(object, ..., simple = FALSE)

The usage section and the examples in the help page indicate that these functions don't need to be addressed individually, as they are called by simply using `update()` when the `lubridate` library is loaded.

To inspect these functions one can type, e.g., `lubridate:::update.POSIXt` in the console (without passing arguments, and without the parentheses).

Comment: So including lubridate via DESCRIPTION file and `depends` in my package is fine? Afterwards I can use `update(...)` and that is the way you should use the function? Why do I always get the reference `stats::update` and nothing from base?

Comment: I have no experience in developing R packages, so I don't know if the inclusion in the DESCRIPTION file is sufficient. If you specifically want to call these functions, they can be addressed with `lubridate:::update.POSIXt()`. The `stats` package is part of the standard distribution in R, so it is commonly referred to as a "base" library, although there is a separate core library called `base`. It can be taken for granted that `stats::update()` is available. If lubridate, as it seems, exploits function overloading / ad hoc polymorphism, `stats::update()` should suffice after library(lubridate)

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- now()
print(date)
new_date <- update(date, year = 2010, month = 1, day = 1)
print(new_date)
```

Outputs:

"2016-08-04 08:58:08 CEST"

"2010-01-01 08:58:08 CET"

Comment: But what type of function is it? Why is there no `lubridate:::update` function? I'll make the question more precise...

Comment: search for "function overloading" and research the S3 OO class systen in R. Like many functions (e.g. `seq`)  the details of the code specific to the mode of the first argument is obsecured. You don't have to run `seq.Date` for a sequence of dates, or `seq.default` for numbers `seq` understands the input and runs the suitable code for you.