# How can a method for a new class refer to the basic function it's replacing?

Tags: r, function, class, methods

Suppose I want to create a method for a class I've created, but I don't have access to the code of the original function - I just want to build on top of it. Just to give a simple example that doesn't actually do anything:

```
x1<-1
class(x1)<-c("myclass",class(x1))
print.myclass<-function(x) {
                            x<-paste0(x,"foobar")
                            print(x)
                           }
print(x1)
```

If I try to run the last line, it throws the function into a loop and R eventually crashes. The solution I found was to add a line to the function that strips the new class name from `x` before passing it to the original function:

```
print.myclass<-function(x) {x<-paste0(x,"foobar"); class(x)<-class(x)[-1]; print(x)}
```

Is there a better/best practice way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you create an infinite loop: `print(print(...)`.
I don't know what you want to achieve but this might be what you are looking for:

```
x1 <- 1
class(x1) <- c("myclass",class(x1))
print.myclass <- function(x) print.default(x)
print(x1)
```

Perhaps you might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52036040/5784831)

BTW: I don't think your solution really solves the problem. You just delete your new class entry which causes `print` not to use `print.myclass`.

For details see [Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html)

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize function.default is a thing. Does that work for any function with methods? If so, that will resolve my issue.

Comment: I think this is a general concept. See also the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760511/5784831)

Comment: To your BTW - my actual function makes some calculations on my object, but ultimately I want to run it through the default function (imagine if before passing x1 to print default, it does `paste0(x,"foobar")`).